# Problem with created Python 3.6 virtual environment on Ubuntu 20.04 with Pip

Tags: python3, pip, virtualenv

**Subject:** Issue with Segmentation Fault When Running `pip list` in Python 3.6 Virtual Environment

I recently installed Python 3.6 and successfully created a virtual environment. However, when I try to execute the command 'pip list' within the virtual environment, I encounter a segmentation fault error.

I have installed Python 3.6.0 by following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72102435/how-to-install-python3-6-on-ubuntu-22-04/72135545#72135545), and created the virtual environment by following this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70422866/how-to-create-a-venv-with-a-different-python-version).

While installing, I skipped these two commands.

```
co./configure --enable-optimizations  -with-lto  --with-pydebug
```

make -j 8de here

Now, it's giving me a segmentation fault. I am going to try reinstalling it with all the flags.

When I check the Python version and Pip version outside the virtual environment, they are up-to-date.

However, when I check the version inside the virtual environment, it gives me a Python version of 3.6 but gives me an error when calling Pip. I have also tried Pip3.6, but it gives me the same error.

Here are the details of my setup:

- Python 3.6
- Virtual environment created successfully

The specific command and error message:

```bash
$ pip list
Segmentation fault
```

I have already tried upgrading pip within the virtual environment, checking for conflicting packages, and recreating the virtual environment, but the issue persists.

Can anyone guide me on troubleshooting and overcoming this segmentation fault error when running a `pip list` in a Python 3.6 virtual environment?

Comment: This looks like a memory allocation (or other memory related function) caused ... How did you install Python 3.6? Did you compile it from source?

Comment: Python 3.6 is outdated and end-of-life. It is better to use a supported version. Ubuntu 20.04 comes by default with Python 3.8.
Please edit your question and add details on a) how did you install Python 3.6? b) Did you make Python 3.6 the system's default Python (hopefully not!) and c) please show exactly all commands how you did create the venv.

Comment: I have downloaded it and compiled it from the source, while following this l[ink](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72102435/how-to-install-python3-6-on-ubuntu-22-04) I didn’t add the command of ‘’  ./configure --enable-optimizations  -with-lto  --with-pydebug 
make -j 8 ’’ which is for cores, do you think this would be the reason? 
@Raffa

Comment: I have updated the question please do check @noisefloor

Comment: I think there is something wrong in your compiled Python executable when it tries to access memory.

Comment: I have reinstalled it do you have any idea how to install a virtual environment for Python 3.6.15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't installed Python 3.6 correctly because I missed a command mentioned in the instructions.

Please follow the provided link in the question, and Python should run smoothly

the segmentation error was because I missed the following line

```
./configure --enable-optimizations  -with-lto  --with-pydebug
make -j 8  # adjust for number of your CPU cores
```